# NHibernate Query using QueryOver HQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am writing the follow as an NHibernate Query but cannot find a solution using QueryOver as HQL: -

```
IQuery query = SessionFactoryContext.GetCurrentSession()
    .CreateSQLQuery(
@"SELECT s.UserID,
    Username,
    Email,Password,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    City,
    County,
    PostalCode,
    Country 
FROM [dbl].[dbo].[User] s 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbl].[dbo].[groupmembership] g ON s.UserrID = g.UserrID 
WHERE g.UserID IS NULL 
    OR (g.GroupID NOT IN (" + groupID + ")  )")

    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(User)));

return (IList<Subscriber>)query.List<User>();
```

Is there any way possible that this can be written as an NHibernate query?

Many thanks for your help,

Comment: Sorry, but it is not very clear what is the trouble. You have "UserrID" there. User with two Rs.  You want the SQL to be translated to HQL, is that it? If it is, post it again, more clearly. Remove what is not needed, like CurrentSession and SetResultTransformer - or is that giving you trouble too? Also, it wouldn't hurt to post the code for the classes involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
.CreateSQLQuery(
    @"FROM User u left join u.GroupMembership g
    WHERE g.User is null
      OR g.GroupId not in (:groupids)"
.SetParameterList("groupids", groupIds)
.List<User>();
```

Given that GroupMembership is a property of user and User and GroupId are properties of the GroupMembership. (If GroupId is the primary key, it can be simplified).